# vue-router : Failed to resolve async component default: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I keep getting this error while trying Vue component import with Vue router.

Here is my `main_app.js`:

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
  {
    path: '/home',
    component: () => import('./list.vue')
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, 
  // mode: 'history'
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

And this is my `list.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div id="right"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'list',
    data: function () {
        return {
            text: 'some-text'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Tried making this change but its not working and I reverted.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`
  // mode: 'history'
  output: {
    path: '/js',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to use dynamic import otherwise? Because if you are using babel, this plugin is required for syntax parsing [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/)

Comment: I am not using babel.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I tried this and it worked. Not sure if this is the perfect solution.

I changed the code to this.

`list.vue`

```
export default {
    name: 'list',
    data: function () {
        return {
            text: 'some-text'
        }
    },
    template: '<template>    <div id="right"></div> </template>',
}
```